QGIS alternative for browsing WMS/WMTS service provided by Geoserver
I maintain a geoserver that provides 100+ layers and layer groups using WMS/WMTS with and without GeoWebCache. I need a tool for quick testing of how they behave while being served by the geoserver, grouping them by workspaces, sorting by name, title, etc. A normal "Add WMS/WMTS connection" is inefficient for my task.
Is there any plugin for QGIS which provides such features? Perhaps there is an alternative to QGIS for such a task?
